# How to define an __init__ function in a class including a self keyword based on json key

Tags: python, json, rest

I have a json str which includes a key called "self" coming from an API. In general would like to pass the dictionary to a class, but one of the given keys (self) leads into an issue. No surprise. But I don't know how to fix it.

My class looks like this:

```
class Issue:
    def __init__(self, expand, fields, key, self):
        self.expand = expand
        self.assignee = fields['assignee']['displayName']
        self.key = key
        self.self = self
    
    @classmethod
    def from_json(cls, json_dict):
        return cls(**json_dict)
```

To instantinate the object I write:

```
Issue.from_json(json_dictionary)
```

I receive a Type error I'm not able to fix:

```
TypeError: __init__() got multiple values for argument 'self'
```

I already tried different versions with leading underscores and so on, but that doesnt help. If I do this:

```
class Issue:
    def __init__(self, expand, fields, key, aSelf):
        self.expand = expand
        self.assignee = fields['assignee']['displayName']
        self.key = key
        self.self = aSelf
    
    @classmethod
    def from_json(cls, json_dict):
        return cls(**json_dict)
```

The error message stays the same. Could you please explain to me how to handle such issues?

Comment: Your example with `aSelf` doesn't work because `json_dict` contains key `self` and when you do `**json_dict` no matter which argument names you've defined in `__init__()` signature; Python will pass all keys from `json_dict` as argument names and their values as arguments so you end up with another `self`. To make it work you'd need to change `json_dict` in `from_json()` and rename key `self` to `aSelf`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Calling the first argument of a method `self` is just a convention. The name isn't special. You don't technically have to call it that. You can call it something else, if you have a good reason:

```
def __init__(self_, expand, fields, key, self):
    self_.expand = expand
    self_.assignee = fields['assignee']['displayName']
    self_.key = key
    self_.self = self
```

Answer (score 0):

this is because keys in your `json_dictionary` are not match the constructor of your class. try following:

```py
class Issue:
    def __init__(_self_, **kwargs):
        if 'expand' in kwargs:
            _self_.expand = kwargs['expand']
        ... # same for the rest of values

    @classmethod
    def from_json(cls, json_dict):
        return cls(**json_dict)
```

Comment: This isn't going to fix the "multiple values for argument 'self'" issue.

Comment: That will not work since if you put `self` key in `**kwargs` Python interpreter will hit same issue when processing arguments (double-`self` will be ambiguous).

Comment: okay, it might be, if in the `json_dict` there is a `self` key. updated the answer.

Comment: also, my solution will work with arbitrary number of keys in the `json_dict`